# postgres select all not working

Tags: postgresql, django-models, psql

I am trying to do a select all on my postgresql table with psql and I am getting a relation does not exist error even though when I run \dt the table clearly does exist.  When I enter \d I get:

```
public | OwnershipDocument        | table    | iswdp
public | OwnershipDocument_id_seq | sequence | iswdp
```

When I enter:

```
select * from OwnershipDocument;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  relation "ownershipdocument" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from OwnershipDocument;
```

I have no idea why this is not working.  This database was created with the Django ORM.

Answer (score 5):

`select * from "OwnershipDocument"`. You need quotes because of the uppercase characters.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you so much.